# Javascript - rename confirm() buttons

Tags: javascript, confirm

By default, there are two buttons:"ok" and "cancel" in confirm().
Is there a way to rename them?

Comment: No.  `confirm()` uses a dialog built-in to the browser.  There is no way to change the buttons.

Comment: Sure, change the language of your browser and OS, and they change, tada!

Comment: On the positive side, if you cannot rename them, you shouldn't worry for internationalizing them - that's entirely browser's job. )

Comment: You should worry about the labels and give more descriptive texts instead of the browser's generic labels. Having “Delete file” on a button less likely to mess something up (be misunderstood) than labeling it “Ok”.

Comment: Not a drop in replacement, but very cool none-the-less.  http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-confirm

According to the standard that defines `confirm()`, there is no way to specify custom button labels.

The browser must display a "positive or negative" prompt (e.g. OK/Cancel) to comply with HTML5.

Answer (score 6):

No, there isn't. Confirm only takes one argument and that is the message itself.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/user-prompts.html#dom-confirm

Keep in mind these dialogs are modal and blocking, which means once they are executed you lose control over the program flow. You'd be on a safer route if you implemented your dialogs using a javascript library of your choice or building yours.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way **IF** you use a custom modal to confirm. Something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').on('click', function () {
    myApp.confirm('Are you sure?', 'Title', function () {
      $('.btn-no').text("No");
      $('.btn-yes').text("Yes");
  });
});
```

Comment: That's not *changing* `confirm`, that's *not using* `confirm`.

Comment: @ChrisMartin I think that I was very clear when I said: 'custom modal to confirm' ;)

Comment: @IrfanMomin it doesn't override OK/Cancel buttons. This will use another way with a custom modal to treat this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the buttons of the default confirm popup. A workaround is to recreate the whole popup in JavaScript. One such workaround is http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation