# Can I change options in confirm(); in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, confirm

Is there anyway I can change the options for the JavaScript `confirm();` function? I want the options to be red and green so I can do this.

```js
var color = confirm("Do you like red or green better");
if(color == true) {
  document.body.style.background = red;
} else {
  document.body.style.background = green;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885897/javascript-rename-confirm-buttons

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.

That happens for security reasons, styling the `Confirm` and `Cancel` buttons would open doors for attackers to abuse this feature in sort of obvious ways (Making the `Cancel` button hard to see, changing `Confirm` to `Cancel`, etc)

You can create a customised modal pop-up, though. Many CSS frameworks and Javascript plugins provide a basic and easy to use template for that, like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/reveal.html), and [assorted jQuery](http://fancybox.net/)  [and vanilla Javascript plugins](http://github.hubspot.com/vex/)

Comment: I doubt it is for security.

Comment: Translation, standardization, consistent experience among different browsers might be other reasons. Omitted for convenience. Specification: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/user-prompts.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't customize `confirm` function.

If you really need to dialog customization, I recommend this. [jQuery UI - Modal confirmation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation)