# Make a div invisible in JavaScript after confirmation

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a `div` visible when clicking on a button. Button should ask Yes/No confirmation. `Div` should be visible only when user clicks on 'Yes'.

My code is here

```
    <div id="Mydiv" style="display:none;" >Haiii</div>
    <input type="button" name="answer" value="Show Div" onclick="confirm_hide(this)"/>
```

JavaScript

```
function confirm_hide(ele){

   if (confirm('Do you wish to hide?')) {
   ele.style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById('Mydiv').style.display = 'block';
    return true;
   } else return false;
    }
```

Comment: What error you are getting? what is happening now?

Comment: `confirm` prompts with `OK` - `Cancel` - you can't use confirm for a `Yes` - `No` choice ... other than that, your code works as long as the function is defined BEFORE the `input` with the `onclick` attribute ... this is where using `addEventListener` is possibly a better choice than an `onclick` attribute

Comment: You are not describing the problem, what error are you getting? whats actually the problem, it seems to work fine

Comment: well, one problem is the requirement that the "button should ask Yes/No confirmation" - which is not possible using confirm

Answer (score 6):

```js
function clicked() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    if(confirm('Hello ' + name + ', great to see you!'))
    {
        document.getElementById('nameDiv').innerHTML = 'Hello ' + name + ', great to see you!';
        document.getElementById('mainDiv').style.display = "none";
    }
    
}
```

```html
<div id="mainDiv">
    <input type="text" class="form" name="name" placeholder="Your name here!" id="name"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="clicked();" value="I'm ready!"/>
</div>
<br>
    <div id="nameDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. [According to a similar question posted before there is no way to
   change the confirm dialogs button.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885897/javascript-rename-confirm-buttons)
2. I would suggest you can use bootstrap modal or jQueryUI.

   [There is even a workaround in the jQueryUI for this.](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation)
3. Or you can use bootstrap Modal. [Here is the link for it](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

I hope my suggestions help with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
function confirm_hide(ele){
    if (confirm('Do you wish to hide?')) {
        ele.style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('Mydiv').style.display = 'block';
        return true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('Mydiv').style.display = 'none';
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: no point in the else hiding #Mydiv, because the button will not be visible if #Mydiv is visible :p

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this also:

```js
function confirm_hide(ele){
  if(confirm('Do you wish to hide?')){
    document.getElementById('Mydiv').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('mainDiv').style.display = 'none';
  }
  }
```

```html
<div id="Mydiv" style="display:none;" >Haiii</div>
<div id="mainDiv">    
<input type="button" name="answer" value="Show Div" onclick="confirm_hide()"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div id="Mydiv" style="display:none;" >Haiii</div>
<input type="button" name="answer" value="Show" class="confirm">
```

JS

```
var div    = document.getElementById("mydiv");
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("confirm");

button.addEventListener('click',confirm_hide());


function confirm_hide(){

var hide =  confirm('Do you wish to hide?');  

if(hide == true){
    button.style.display = 'none';
    div.style.display = 'block';
}
else{
      button.style.display = 'block';
      div.style.display = 'none';
    }


}
```