# How to ask for confirmation before performing an actionin ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a delete button where I want to ask for confirmation before deleting the record. I want to put a custom message in German and German terms for 'OK' and 'cancel'.

```
<%= button_to 'Record löschen', action: 'delete_all_record', id: params[:id], redirect_back: params[:redirect_back]%>
```

so, when I press record löshen button it should ask for confirmation and then perform the deletion action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick tip for rails 7

```
<%= button_to 'Record löschen',
  {action: 'delete_all_record', id: params[:id]},
  form: {data: {turbo_confirm: 'Sind Sie sicher?'}} %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`button_to`](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActionView%2FHelpers%2FUrlHelper:button_to) with the data attribute `confirm` like this:

```
<%= button_to(
      'Record löschen', 
      { action: 'delete_all_record', id: params[:id] },
      data: { confirm: "Sind Sie sicher?" } %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Instead of OK and cancel I want ,"Ja, löschen" and "Abbrechen". How can i do that ?

Comment: @code_L there's no way to [rename confirm() buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885897/javascript-rename-confirm-buttons). You could create your own dialog though.